# LVM thin provisioning

Tags: linux, lvm

I am looking to create a group of thin provisioned LVs using LVM.

Is it possible to create a volume group in which every logical volume created is by default thin provisioned, or perhaps there is another way of doing this?

This would be for RHEL6.

Comment: Might be better addressed in SuperUser or UNIX SE.

Answer (score 4):

LVM Thin Provisioning is currently a proposed feature of RHEL 7, it is not available by default in RHEL 6.

Edit: I was wrong, LVM thin provisioning was officially added in RHEL 6.4

Comment: Can it be added with installing device-mapper-persistent-data ?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, it was added in RHEL 6.4.  Use the '-T' option in lvcreate.  See new features in 6.4 at: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration-en-US.pdf

Comment: Awesome thanks for that. Do you happen to know if it is possible to make the entire Volume group thin provisioned?

Answer (score 3):

From the [release announcement](http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2012-January/msg00018.html):

> After a long break, we've issued a new LVM2 release, 2.02.89.
>
> ...
>
> This release includes experimental support for thinly-provisioned
> logical volumes using the new device-mapper thin provisioning target
> in kernel 3.2.

As of writing, Debian stable has [lvm2 at version 2.02.95-7](http://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/lvm2); Ubuntu is [summarised](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2) as:

- 13.04 (current): 2.02.95
- 12.04 (current LTS): 2.02.66
- 10.04 (previous LTS): 2.02.54

Comment: But it is currently disabled in Wheezy (LVM 2.02.95-7) as thin_check binaries are missing.

Answer (score 1):

Thin provisioning for LVMs will be introduced in RHEL 7. If everything goes well...

**EDIT:** As stated above, RHEL 6.4 introduced **experimental** support for thin provisioned LVMs. I personally would stay as far as possible on production systems from experimental stuff.

Comment: Actually, the experimental support referenced above is from 01/2012.  The support added to RHEL 6.4 was not indicated as a Technology Preview, therefore should be fully supported by Red Hat at this time.